# Developing UCWA applications for Skype for Business Online

Tags: java, office365, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, ucwa

I'm trying to develop a simple java client that needs to access Skype for Business APIs in order to setup an online meeting (i.e. I need to retrieve a simple setup meeting URL by invoking an UCWA API).

I followed this Microsoft tutorial step-by-step:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline

I have an Office 365 Business Premium license and I configured a custom domain (correctly registered and added at the zone DNS file);

1. I configured and registered my java client app on Azure (taking care to assign required delegated permission for Skype for Business capabilities);
2. I performed the Sign-in phase and Azure is able to recognize me;
3. I performed the Autodiscovery phase in order to retrieve the user's UCWA home pool;
4. I sent a GET request to the Azure oauth2 endpoint with response 401 error (and this is the expected behaviour by the authentication handshake);
5. Unfortunately, I failed when I request an access token using implicit grant flow: Azure responds with a Sign-In HTML page rather than the json object containing the oauth2 access token.

What's wrong on this GET request?

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=id_token
&client_id=my_application_client_id
&redirect_uri=configured_redirect_uri
&state=UUID_generated_code
&resource=UCWA_home_pool 
HTTP/1.1
```

This GET URL looks like that one used for the Sign-In phase (step 3); I suspect that it isn't the right request URL.

I tryed to put my domain on the URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_domain_name/oauth2/authorize
```

and I tryed to put a common domain name (as reported on the documentation):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
```

But Azure still reponds with a Sign-In page (and response code 200 OK).

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the oauth2AllowImplicitFlow property in manifest of your application after downloading the latest manifest file. It should be set to true for this to wrok. If it's still false, only then I would expect the redirect to sign-in page as you're seeing.

More detailed steps here -
[Configure your app for OAuth implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/registeringyourapplicationinazuread#configure-your-app-for-oauth-implicit-grant-flow)